# c# application is crashing when the server is down

Tags: c#

I'm using this code, to fetch the latest version of my app in *Form1_Load*:

```
string result1 = null;
string url1 = "http://site.com/version.html";
WebResponse response1 = null;
StreamReader reader1 = null;

try
{
   HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url1);
   request1.Method = "GET";
   response1 = request1.GetResponse();
   reader1 = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
   result1 = reader1.ReadToEnd();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   // show the error if any.                
 }
 finally
 {
    if (reader1 != null)
         reader1.Close();
    if (response1 != null)
         response1.Close();
 }
```

The problem is that when I shut the server down the whole application is stucking and a window is popping out,saying:

> Unable to connect to the remote server

Which seems legit.

Is there a way to bypass this crash (when the server is down) and break out of the version checking?

Comment: Is the code above exactly the code in question, or did you leave out stuff where the comment says " // show the error if any"?

Comment: what line does it crash on when the server is down.

Comment: its just popping a window saying: "Unable to connect to the remote server" and the app is closing automaticaly

Comment: @jwrush yes,its the problematic code.

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception (if available in the popup). I'd suspect the problem here is related somehow to threading, i.e. the request made is executed on another thread and the exception handling wont trigger due to that.

Comment: @allu I think I found what's wrong.. Is there a way to check if the server is down,or is there a way to read the server answer lines without saving it somewhere?I saved the  result1 into a text file and it returned 2 blank lines.

Comment: Side notes: On code: please change `finally` to proper `using`. On question format: avoid thankyou notes and other "I'm learning" unrelated text. When posting code try to avoid too many whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional catch block that catches the specific Exception type that you're seeing... the code will look like...

```
try
{
//*yadda yadda yadda*
}
catch (System.Net.WebException WebEx)
{
//*Correctly set up a situation where the rest of your program will know there was a connection problem to the website.*
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//*Do the error catching you do now*
}
finally
{
//*yadda yadda*
}
```

This construction will allow you to handle WebExceptions differently from other kinds of exceptions: note that all Exceptions derive from one base class, Exception, and you can make your own for uses like this.

Comment: WebException inherits from Exception, thus the existing exception filter in the sample code posted by Code Beast will already catch it.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question.  I thought the comment in the code example was describing code that was omitted from the example, and so the asker wants to bypass that when he can't connect.  Asking for clarification.

Comment: hey jwrush,I just tryed that and my app is still crashing :(